# C# windows runtime component for UWP keybd_event

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to control the windows system control from inside an UWP. Because that isn't possible I have created a service app as windows runtime component. Then I googled and found this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms; // of course I have no forms
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace UniversalSandbox
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENTEDKEY = 1;
    public const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0;
    public const int VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK = 0xB0;
    public const int VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 0xB3;
    public const int VK_MEDIA_PREV_TRACK = 0xB1;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void keybd_event(byte virtualKey, byte scanCode,uint flags, IntPtr extraInfo);
```

But there is an error for `keybd_even`t:

The method ... is external and has no attributes

Is there a solution?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? In general UWP apps can't fake input, but there are some capabilities for testing inside your own app. FWIW, the `keybd_event` documentation says to use `SendInput` instead.

Comment: Ok, I have a bluetooth controller named NUIMO. There is only a demo UWP app and a sdk for windows. I'm only a hobby programmer and I have read - as you write - that an UWP app cannot control input.  My idea was, to use a runtime component to do that for the app. I want to use the keybd_event to create some keyboard events to control the system volume. I think it would be no problem for a windows form app, but I have difficulties with my runtime component.